# Can we have many adapters for Alamofire session manager?

Tags: alamofire

I would like to have many adapters to the same SessionManager, is it possible?

My usecase is:

setup default header from an adapter

if basic_auth: add basic_auth_adapter

if token_auth: add token_auth_adapter

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently in Alamofire 4 you can only use 1 `RequestAdapter` with each `SessionManager`. We designed it this way because to help you simplify things and to avoid order issues if there are multiple adapters.

You could easily add all those functions to the same adapter. Our intention was that if an adapter became way too complicated, you could break out the logic into multiple smaller objects. One way you could possibly do this would be to create a smaller adapter for each type of URL request. Then the main adapter called by the `SessionManager` would inspect the URL request and call the appropriate smaller adapter.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution:

```
struct MasterAdapter: RequestAdapter {

    let adapters: [RequestAdapter]

    func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = urlRequest
        try adapters.forEach({ request = try $0.adapt(request) })
        return request
    }

}
```

Now set MasterAdapter with it's child adapters as your adapter on your default or custom SessionManager.

```
SessionManager.default.adapter = MasterAdapter(adapters: [MyAdapter1(), MyAdapter2()])
```

Comment: Thanks @diegotrevisan! But shouldn't `request` be returned at the end of the method, instead of `urlRequest`?

Comment: @ChristophP Ooops, you are right! I'm fixing it, thanks!